# How is PhoneApplicationService.Current.State remembered

Tags: windows-phone-7

The `PhoneApplicationService.Current.State` dictionary can be used for persisting data when the application gets tombstoned.

I wonder how my objects get persisted in this dictionary, are they serialized and then stored somewhere, or is the whole dictionary kept in memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The objects are serialized (using DataContractSerializer) and then kept in memory. This is different (and faster) compared to IsolatedStorage which saves the data to disk.